# Use a variable as function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a method in which i will pass a function_name as parameter to another function.

On the other function, the parameter will be treated as a function

here's my code example

```
<div class="btn_crt_acct" onclick="toggle_object('register_div','slideDown');">
            CREATE AN ACCOUNT
</div>
```

whch will call a function like this

```
function toggle_object(obj,fun)
{
    $('#'+obj).fun('slow'); 
    // fun => slideDown
    // so $('#'+obj).fun('slow'); => $('#'+obj).slideDown('slow'); 
}
```

but i am doing something wrong as it states an error in console, $fun(..) is not a function.

How can i make it work perfectly??

Thanks

Comment: Why not just pass the function directly? e.g. onclick="toggle_object('register_div', slideDown);">

Comment: @FelixKling it's a dupe, but it's also an XY problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do that with bracket notation

```
$('#'+obj)[fun]('slow');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcwerbLd/)

But why not use a proper event handler, and `slideToggle` if you intend to toggle it

```
$('.btn_crt_acct').on('click', function() {
    $('#register_div').slideToggle();
});
```